# How to define a grid of whole height for navbar and two rows?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I defined a CSS grid to dispose the layout as:

```
nav content
nav footer
```

So `nav` will take whole page height and a given width and the remain space would be divided in: content height and footer height.

I defined as:

```scss
$nav-width: 8.75rem;
$navbar-height: 6.125rem;
$footer-height: 6.438rem;

.auth-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr $footer-height;
  grid-template-columns: $nav-width 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav content' 'nav footer';
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

However what I get is this grid:

[image: Grid layout where 1 column and 1 row is filled with nav and the second column and row is filled with content and footer. But there's a third row?]

It seems to render a third row? How can I fill the whole height with nav and the rest divide in two columns for content and footer, respectively?

Comment: Please share the (relevant) minimal HTML that you're working with, and also read the guidance over at "*[ask]*."

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate what you wanted.

```css
body, html {
   height: 100%; 
}

.grid {
   display: grid; 

   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   
   gap: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
  
#nav {
   height:100%;
   background-color: #DA975D; 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 1;

   grid-row-end: 5;
   grid-column-end: 2;  
}

#part1 {

   background-color: #9C55FD; 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 2;

   grid-row-end: 3;
   grid-column-end: 6;
}

#part2 {

   background-color: #8FDD77; 
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-column-start: 2;

   grid-row-end: 5;
   grid-column-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="nav">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="part1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="part2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```